# x86 Assembly: Writing a Program to Test Memory Functionality for Entire 1MB of Memory

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, intel, masm

Goal:
I need to write a program that tests the write functionality of an entire 1MB of memory on a byte by byte basis for a system using an Intel 80186 microprocessor. In other words, I need to write a 0 to every byte in memory and then check if a 0 was actually written. I need to then repeat the process using a value of 1. Finally, any memory locations that did not successfully have a 0 or 1 written to them during their respective write operation needs to be stored on the stack.

Discussion:
I am an Electrical Engineering student in college (Not Computer Science) and am relatively new to x86 assembly language and MASM611. I am not looking for a complete solution. However, I am going to need some guidance.

Earlier in the semester, I wrote a program that filled a portion of memory with 0's. I believe that this will be a good starting point for my current project.

Source Code For Early Program:

```
;****************************************************************************
;Program Name: Zeros
;File Name: PROJ01.ASM
;DATE: 09/16/14
;FUNCTION: FILL A MEMORY SEGMENT WITH ZEROS
;HISTORY:
;AUTHOR(S):
;****************************************************************************

NAME ZEROS

MYDATA SEGMENT
MYDATA ENDS

MYSTACK SEGMENT STACK
                DB              0FFH  DUP(?)
                End_Of_Stack    LABEL BYTE
MYSTACK ENDS



ASSUME  SS:MYSTACK, DS:MYDATA, CS:MYCODE
MYCODE SEGMENT
START:  MOV AX, MYSTACK
        MOV SS, AX
        MOV SP, OFFSET End_Of_Stack
        MOV AX, MYDATA
        MOV DS, AX

        MOV AX, 0FFFFh                  ;Moves a Hex value of 65535 into AX
        MOV BX, 0000h                   ;Moves a Hex value of 0 into BX

        CALL Zero_fill                  ;Calls procedure Zero_fill

        MOV AX, 4C00H                   ;Performs a clean exit
        INT 21H

Zero_fill   PROC NEAR                   ;Declares procedure Zero_fill with near directive
                MOV DX, 0000h           ;Moves 0H into DX
                MOV CX, 0000h           ;Moves 0H into CX. This will act as a counter.
Start_Repeat:   INC CX                  ;Increments CX by 1
                MOV [BX], DX            ;Moves the contents of DX to the memory address of BX
                INC BX                  ;Increments BX by 1
                CMP CX, 10000h          ;Compares the value of CX with 10000H. If equal, Z-flag set to one.
                JNE Start_Repeat        ;Jumps to Start_Repeat if CX does not equal 10000H.
                RET                     ;Removes 16-bit value from stack and puts it in IP
Zero_fill   ENDP                        ;Ends procedure Zero_fill

MYCODE ENDS
END START
```

Requirements:
1. Employ explicit segment structure.
2. Use the ES:DI register pair to address the test memory area.
3. Non destructive access: Before testing each memory location, I need to store the original contents of the byte. Which needs to be restored after testing is complete.
4. I need to store the addresses of any memory locations that fail the test on the stack.
5. I need to determine the highest RAM location.

Plan:
1. In a loop: Write 0000H to memory location, Check value at that mem location, `PUSH` values of ES and DI to the stack if check fails.
2. In a loop: Write FFFFH to memory location, Check value at that mem location, `PUSH` values of ES and DI to the stack if check fails.

Source Code Implementing Preliminary Plan:

```
;****************************************************************************
;Program Name: Memory Test
;File Name: M_TEST.ASM
;DATE: 10/7/14
;FUNCTION: Test operational status of each byte of memory between a starting
;          location and an ending location
;HISTORY: Template code from Assembly Project 1
;AUTHOR(S):
;****************************************************************************

NAME M_TEST

MYDATA SEGMENT
MYDATA ENDS

MYSTACK SEGMENT STACK
                DB              0FFH  DUP(?)
                End_Of_Stack    LABEL BYTE
MYSTACK ENDS

ESTACK SEGMENT COMMON
ESTACK ENDS

ASSUME  SS:MYSTACK, DS:MYDATA, CS:MYCODE, ES:ESTACK
MYCODE SEGMENT
START:          MOV AX, MYSTACK
                MOV SS, AX
                MOV SP, OFFSET End_Of_Stack
                MOV AX, MYDATA
                MOV DS, AX

                MOV AX, FFFFH           ;Moves a Hex value of 65535 into AX
                MOV BX, 0000H           ;Moves a Hex value of 0 into BX

                CALL M_TEST             ;Calls procedure M_TEST

                MOV AX, 4C00H           ;Performs a clean exit
                INT 21H

M_TEST      PROC NEAR                   ;Declares procedure M_TEST with near directive
                MOV DX, 0000H           ;Fill DX with 0's
                MOV AX, FFFFH           ;Fill AX with 1's
                MOV CX, 0000H           ;Moves 0H into CX. This will act as a counter.
Start_Repeat:   MOV [BX], DX            ;Moves the contents of DX to the memory address of BX
                CMP [BX], 0000H         ;Compare value at memory location [BX] with 0H. If equal, Z-flag set to one.
                JNE SAVE                ;IF Z-Flag NOT EQUAL TO 0, Jump TO SAVE
                MOV [BX], AX            ;Moves the contents of AX to the memory address of BX
                CMP [BX], FFFFH         ;Compare value at memory location [BX] with FFFFH. If equal, Z-flag set to one.
                JNE SAVE                ;IF Z-Flag NOT EQUAL TO 0, Jump TO SAVE
                INC CX                  ;Increments CX by 1
                INC BX                  ;Increments BX by 1
                CMP CX, 10000H          ;Compares the value of CX with 10000H. If equal, Z-flag set to one.
                JNE Start_Repeat        ;Jumps to Start_Repeat if CX does not equal 10000H.
SAVE:           PUSH ES
                PUSH DI
                RET                     ;Removes 16-bit value from stack and puts it in IP
M_TEST      ENDP                        ;Ends procedure Zero_fill

MYCODE ENDS
END START
```

My commenting might not be accurate.

Questions:
1. How do I use ES:DI to address the test memory area?
2. What is the best way to hold on to the initial memory value so that I can replace it when I'm done testing a specific memory location? I believe registers AX - DX are already in use.

Also, if I have updated code and questions, should I post it on this same thread, or should I create a new post with a link to this one?

Any other advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: With respect to requirement #3, where are you allowed to save that area which you are testing ?

Comment: Does he let you away with this instruction ? `CMP CX, 10000h`

Comment: Firstly, no area is specified with respect to Req. 3. Secondly, I believe `CMP CX, 10000H` is allowed. Is there a reason it shouldn't be?

Comment: I believe that `10000` is greater than 16 bits, and as such, is more than the CX register will hold. I suggest you debug it and see what you get in CX when you execute that instruction. Best I can tell, it's supposed to be illegal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I use ES:DI to address the test memory area?

E.g. `mov al, es:[di]`

> What is the best way to hold on to the initial memory value so that I can replace it when I'm done testing a specific memory location? I believe registers AX - DX are already in use.

Right. You could use `al` to store the original value and have `0` and `1` pre-loaded in `bl` and `cl` and then do something like this (off the top of my head):

```
mov al, es:[di] // load/save original value

mov es:[di], bl // store zero
cmp bl, es:[di] // check that it sticks
jne @pushbad    // jump if it didn't

mov es:[di], cl // same for 'one'
cmp cl, es:[di]
jne @pushbad

mov es:[di], al // restore original value
jmp @nextAddr

@pushbad:
mov es:[di], al // restore original value (may be redundant as the mem is bad)
push es
push di

@nextAddr:
...
```

Comment: Should I initialize ES like I did for DS and SS? Also, I am not familiar with DI. Could I just replace every BX with DI in my code? That way, DI would be my memory offset value instead of BX?

Comment: Yes, in this context either one should work the same. You can conveniently load a segment:offset pair with e.g. `les di` - or you can load the `es` register separately with e.g. `push <segment value>` `pop es`.

Answer (score 0):

Some words about for to test also the memory location that our own routine is claimed. We can copy and run our routine into the framebuffer of the display device.

..

Note: If we want to store or compare a memory location with an immediate value, then we have to specify how many bytes we want to access. (But in opposite of it with using a register as a source, or a target, the assembler already knows the size of it, so we do not need to specify.)

Accessing one byte of one address (with an immediate value):

```
CMP BYTE[BX], 0     ; with NASM (Netwide Assembler)
MOV BYTE[BX], 0

CMP BYTE PTR[BX], 0 ; with MASM (Microsoft Macro Assembler)
MOV BYTE PTR[BX], 0
```

Accessing two bytes of two adresses together
(executing faster, if the target address is even aligned):

```
CMP WORD[BX], 0     ; with NASM
MOV WORD[BX], 0

CMP WORD PTR[BX], 0 ; with MASM
MOV WORD PTR[BX], 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the assumption that any location in RAM might be faulty; then this means you can't use RAM to store your code or your data. This includes temporary usage - for example, you can't temporarily store your code in RAM and then copy it to display memory, because you risk copying corrupted code from RAM to display memory.

With this in mind; the only case where this makes sense is code in ROM testing the RAM - e.g. during the firmware's POST (Power On Self Test). Furthermore; this means that you can't use the stack at all - not for keeping track of faulty areas, or even for calling functions/routines.

Note that you might assume that you can test a small area (e.g. find the first 1 KiB that isn't faulty) and then use that RAM for storing results, etc. This would be a false assumption.

For RAM faults there are many causes. The first set of causes is "open connection" and "shorted connection" on either the address bus or the data bus. For a simple example, if address line 12 happens to be open circuit, the end result will be that the first 4 KiB always has identical contents to the second 4 KiB of RAM. You can test the first 4 KiB of RAM as much as you like and decide it's "good", but then when you test the second 4 KiB of RAM you trash the contents of the first 4 KiB of RAM.

There is a "smart sequence" of tests. Specifically, test the address lines from highest to lowest (e.g. write different values to 0x000000 and 0x800000 and check that they're both correct; then do the same for 0x000000 and 0x400000, then 0x000000 and 0x200000, and so on until you get to addresses 0x000000 and 0x000001). However, the way RAM chips are connected to the CPU is not necessarily as simple as a direct mapping. For example, maybe the highest bit of the address selects which bank of RAM; and in that case you'd have to test both 0x000000 and 0x400000 and also 0x800000 and 0xC00000 to test both banks.

Once you're sure the address lines work; then you can do similar for data lines and the RAM itself. The most common test is called a "walking ones" test; where you store 0x01, then 0x02, and so on (up to 0x80). This detects things like "sticky bits" (e.g. where a bit's state happens to be "stuck" to its neighbour's state). If you only write (e.g.) 0x00 and test it then write 0xFF and test it, then you will miss most RAM faults.

Also; be very careful with "open connection". On some machines bus capacitance can play tricks on you, where you write a value and the bus capacitance "stores" the previous value, so that when you read it back it looks like it's correct even when there's no connection. To avoid this risk, you need to write a different value in between - e.g. write 0x55 to the address you're testing, then write 0xAA somewhere else, then read the original value back (and hope you get 0x55 because the RAM works, and not 0xAA). With this in mind (for performance) you may consider doing "walking ones" in one area of RAM while also doing "walking zeros" in the next area of RAM; so that you're always alternating between reading a value from one area and reading the inverted value from the other.

Finally, some RAM problems depend on noise, temperature, etc. In these cases you can do extremely thorough RAM tests, say that it's all perfect, then suffer from RAM corruption 2 minutes afterwards. This is why (e.g.) the typical advice is to run something like "memtest" for 8 hours or so if you really want to test RAM properly.

Comment: Interesting, but a little outside of the scope of my current Lab project. Thanks.